# Unable to position a div fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

I've a fixed positioned div which is not sticking to the corner in mobile devices.
Also, the div is not visible if values other than `top:0;left:0;` is added to fix the position in other corners.

I've a media query for mobile devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 220px)
{
    #chatbotOut {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2147483001!important;
        max-height: none!important;
        right: 0!important;
        bottom: 0!important;
        border-radius: 0!important;
    }
}
```

The issue can be found in [here](https://www.avnet.com/shop/us).
Switch to devtools of chrome and select any mobile device and see.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks like you may have conflicting styles within the iFrame inside #chatbotOut

Comment: @AlexMulchinock I also think like that, though, not much favourable

Comment: Your site isn't particularly responsive, and is very confusing to navigate. It shows if I do it on an iPad inside chrome though

Comment: @AndyHolmes What could be the issue for the icon not showing in mobile?. But it's showing properly in IOS devices. Not in Android.

Comment: Without your media query, does it show? Otherwise it may be a conflict with the code coming from the iFrame

Comment: Yes. Media query is to make the bot window occupy the whole space of viewport in mobile devices.